# Place Partial View Html elements below the Main View's Html elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

My Goal is to make a CreatePartialCategoryView within an index View. View loads just fine, bet there is just one small problem:

The CreatePartialView html elements are placed above the Index View's html elements. It looks like this at the moment:

[image: The "Create a new Category" form field is from the CreatePartialCategoryView. The "Categories part is from the index view. I want index part with the list template to appear above the create a new category."]

Here's the code for the index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Category/CreatePartial.cshtml",new  GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel());


@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Categories";
 }

<h2>Categories</h2>


<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Here's the code of the CreatePartialView:

```
@model GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Create a new Category</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
 }



@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And this is the code for the CategoryController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BLL;
using ClassLibrary.Entities;
using DAL;
using GUI.Models;


namespace GUI.Controllers
{
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<Category> _repository;
    private CategoryHandler _categoryHandler;

    public CategoryController() : this(new Repository<Category>())
    { 
    }

    public CategoryController(IRepository<Category> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _categoryHandler = new CategoryHandler(repository);
    }






    //
    // GET: /Category/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var categories = _categoryHandler.GetAllCategories();
        var categoryViewModels = new List<CategoryViewModel>();

        foreach (Category category in categories)
        {
            var viewModel = new CategoryViewModel();
            viewModel.Id = category.Id;
            viewModel.Name = category.Name;
            categoryViewModels.Add(viewModel);
        }
        //return View();
        return View(categoryViewModels);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Category/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Category/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Category/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CategoryViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here


                string categoryName = model.Name;
                _categoryHandler.AddNewCategory(categoryName);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");



        }

        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Category/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Category/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Category/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Category/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(Guid id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add delete logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

So, how do I place the CreatePartialView html elements (Create form) below the index View elements (the list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just put the line:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Category/CreatePartial.cshtml",new  GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel());
```

Just below  your table listing the categories?  like :

```
<table class="table">
...
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Category/CreatePartial.cshtml",new  GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but don't you just need to move `@Html.Partial` call below your list in your view?

```
@model IEnumerable<GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Categories";
 }

<h2>Categories</h2>


<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Category/CreatePartial.cshtml",new  GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel());
```